# Add inputs dynamically according to the choice of radio button

Tags: forms, button, radio-button, field

I am using the following code, which is intended to show two inputs after choosing according to the selected radio button.
Only I may have to include it several times, dynamically.
And when I add dynamically, radio buttons appear, but when selecting one, the inputs do not appear.
Would I have to reset the javascript to use it again?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="radiocpfcnpj"]').on("change", function() {
        if (this.checked && this.value == 'cpf') {
            $("#cpfParteProcesso").show();
            $("#cnpjParteProcesso").hide();
            $("#cpfParteProcessoNome").show();
            $("#cnpjParteProcessoNome").hide();
            $("#add_interessado").show();
        } else {
            $("#cnpjParteProcesso").show();
            $("#cpfParteProcesso").hide();
            $("#cnpjParteProcessoNome").show();
            $("#cpfParteProcessoNome").hide();
            $("#add_interessado").show();
        }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //Variáveis
    var html = '<div class="form-group"><label for="cpfParteProcesso">CPF/CNPJ da parte<small class="text-muted"> (escolha a opção)</small></label><div class="form-check"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="cpfProcessoFilho" name="radiocpfcnpj" value="cpf"><label class="form-check-label">CPF</label><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="cnpjProcessoFilho" name="radiocpfcnpj" value="cnpj"><label class="form-check-label">CNPJ</label></div><input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cpfParteProcessoFilho" name="cpfParteProcesso" data-mask><input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cnpjParteProcessoFilho" name="cnpjParteProcesso" data-mask><button id="add_interessado" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm interessado">Remover</button></div>';
    //Adicionar linhas
    $("#add_interessado").click(function(e){
      $("#dadoscpfcnpj").append(html);
      $("#cpfParteProcesso").append(html);
      $("#cpfParteProcessoNome").append(html);
      $("#cnpjParteProcesso").append(html);
      $("#cnpjfParteProcessoNome").append(html);
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dadoscpfcnpj" class="form-group">
                  <label for="cpfParteProcesso">CPF/CNPJ da parte<small class="text-muted"> (escolha a opção)</small></label>
                  <div id="dadoscpfcnpj" class="form-group form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="cpfProcesso" name="radiocpfcnpj" value="cpf">
                    <label class="form-check-label">CPF</label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="cnpjProcesso" name="radiocpfcnpj" value="cnpj">
                    <label class="form-check-label">CNPJ</label>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cpfParteProcesso" name="cpfParteProcesso" data-mask>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cpfParteProcessoNome" name="cpfParteProcessoNome" >
                  <input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cnpjParteProcesso" name="cnpjParteProcesso" data-mask>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control cpfcnpj" id="cnpjParteProcessoNome" name="cnpjParteProcessoNome">
                  <button id="add_interessado" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm interessado" value="cpf">Adicionar interessado</button>               
                </div>
        </div>
```

`

Comment: I run you code in a snippet. But i dont understand your issue please explain aigain. all i see is thats you can only select on radio, and you cant remove an dynamicly inserted form part.

Comment: Oh yeah. I may not have explained it correctly. When I make the option on the radio button (id = "cpfProcesso" or id = "cnpjProcesso"), the fields (id cpfParteProcesso, cpfParteProcessoNome, cnpjParteProcesso e cnpjParteProcessoNome) are shown according to the option. What happens is that I may have to add new records regarding new radio button options. And at this moment, there is no input. My question is whether I would have to reset the javascript for this to happen, as it seems that it is not working properly. Thanks again

Comment: When you add a new record you only add 2 input and you function dont set the function that you create ealier on the first one... And since you use the same name, all the radio button are linked.

Comment: I understand your explanation. I will deepen my study further and as soon as a good solution comes, I post it here for everyone. Thank you very much for your help.